adding tag on cdk script
Sorry, I'm still new and learning on cdk things, I would like to add the following tags if possible on the stack level so that it will propagate to all aws resources that I plan to add. The following tags I plan to add is something like this:
app = pogi
env = poc
tier = panot

my stack.js only has this and I have no clue where to add the tagging
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
// import * as sqs from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sqs';
import * as s3 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3'

export class InfraStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // The code that defines your stack goes here

    // example resource
    // const queue = new sqs.Queue(this, 'InfraQueue', {
    //   visibilityTimeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(300)
    // });

 

    // S3 bucket
    const panotbucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'panotbucket07032024-test', {
      bucketName: 'panotbucket07032024',
      versioned: true,
      publicReadAccess: false
    })
  }
}


Did the answer work?

Tags.of(this).add("myTag", "myValue");
Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Tags.html

may I ask to which file should this be added? on the ts file of lib or bin folder?

The tag will be added to all resources that are created in the scope that you pass to Tags.of() - so choose based on that. If you want it to apply to the stack, you can put it into the stack constructor, where this is the Stack itself.

I added it on the bin/infra.ts and getting now. this error:

infra@0.1.0 build
tsc

bin/infra.ts:9:1 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Tags'.
9 Tags.of(this).add("app", "pogi");


Found 1 error in bin/infra.ts:9

Well yeah, you have to import it.
